# C/C++ recv() with timeout

Tags: c++, c

Hoping someone can help me out. I'm wanting to implement some sort of timeout if my socket is not able to receive data in a certain amount of time... I've looked up ways online but the examples I've looked at doesn't have their recv() in a while loop like mine, they typically just receive the whole buffer that is waiting. Maybe mine just isn't very efficient and someone could point me in a better direction in receiving all the data.

The string that is to be received is not a fixed length which is why I receive 1 at a time because I don't know how big the string might be. As you can see my recv() will receive data until it finds the End of text character ().  The examples with select() I found would use the select before calling receive, but should I be doing that for each go around of my while loop? or maybe call select() before I even enter the while loop?

Anyways, any help is appreciated.

```
string recv_data(int socket){

bool endfound = false;
char temp[1];
string recvstring ;
while(endfound == false)//receives 1 character at a time until ETX(\x03)character is found
{
    if(recv(socket,temp,sizeof(temp),0)<0)
    {
        perror("error in recv data");
    }

    if(memchr(temp,'\x03',1) != NULL) 
    {
        endfound = true;
    }

    recvstring += temp;
    temp[0] = 0;
}

return formatting(recvstring);
}
```

Comment: With this: `recvstring += temp;` did you mean `recvstring += temp[0];`? (otherwise it will go looking for a null terminator)

Comment: You can use SO_RCVTIMEO if your platform supports it, but I agree with you that the whole design is wrong. You don't need to read one byte at a time in networking code.

Comment: I just felt at first since I didn't know the size of the incoming string it was best to recv until it found the end. Thinking about it now I can probably be fine just declare my char to a something big and searching for the end text character to add a null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You must put your socket into non-blocking mode, and use poll().

poll() technically works on regular blocking sockets too; however it's been my experience that there are various subtle differences in semantics and race conditions, when using poll() with blocking sockets, and for best portability I always used non-blocking mode sockets, together with poll(), and careful inspection of the returning value from recv() or read().

Some Google food for you: fcntl(), `F_SETFL`, `O_NONBLOCK`.

Comment: You *can.* Not 'must'. There are other solutions.

Comment: Nevertheless, combining non-blocking mode for the socket with `poll()` (or `select()`) is probably the sanest _portable_ way to enforce a receive timeout.

Comment: I've never heard of poll(). I'll look into that. This could possibly be better for what I'm doing. Thanks.